# Creating a dictionary from a text file Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have to create a dictionary based on a csv file that looks like this:

```
'song, 2000, 184950'
'boom, 2009, 83729'
'boom, 2010, 284500'
'boom, 2011, 203889'
'pow, 2000, 385920'
'pow, 2001, 248930'
```

from this, I have to create a dictionary that consists of the word as a key and then a list of class objects as a value.

This is what I have so far...

```
class Counter():
   __slots__ = ('year', 'count')
   _types = (int, int)

def readfile(file):
   d = dict()
   with open(file) as f:
      for line in f:
          element = line.split(,)
          for word in element:
              if word in d:
                  d[word].append([Count(int(element[1]), int(element[2]))])
              else:
                  d[word] = [Count(int(element[1]), int(element[2]))]
   print(d)
```

the output I'm getting is weird and it is giving me a dictionary similar to what mine should look like but it's using the counts (183930) as the key instead of the name. I also need it to add the class onto the value if it is already listed in the dictionary.

for example, since 'boom' should already be in the dictionary with `{'boom' : Count(year = 2009, count = 83729)}` I want there to be a list of those Count objects under the one value.

expected output:

```
{'song' : [Count(year= 2000, count= 184950)], 'boom' : [Count(year=2009, count=83729),
Count(year=2010, count= 284500), Count(year=2011, count=203889)], 'pow' : ...etc..}
```

Comment: @Martijn are you sure that `'` should be in csv example? I think they made sense around string, but not as sample csv.

Comment: @Vyktor: the OP used this in their sample; I'll leave it to them to remove it.

Comment: Your code is invalid; it is missing quotes (around the comma for example) and the `Counter()` class as posted won't work. Can you please give us *working code*?

Comment: Why are you both looping over the `element` list *and* indexing into it? Why not just use `word = element[0]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this loop:

```
for word in element:
    if word in d:
        d[word].append([Count(int(element[1]), int(element[2]))])
    else:
        d[word] = [Count(int(element[1]), int(element[2]))]
```

You are iterating trough all words on line, so you call (for first line):

```
d['song'].append([Count(int('2000'), int('184950'))])
d['2000'].append([Count(int('2000'), int('184950'))])
d['184950'].append([Count(int('2000'), int('184950'))])
```

Just use:

```
for line in f:
    element = line.split(,)
    word = element[0]
    if word in d:
        d[word].append(Count(int(element[1]), int(element[2])))
    else:
        d[word] = [Count(int(element[1]), int(element[2]))]
```

You also can replace your condition `if word in d` if you use [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
import collections

def readfile(file):
   d = collections.defaultdict(list)
   with open(file) as f:
      for line in f:
          element = line.split(,)
          word = element[0]
          d[word].append(Count(int(element[1]), int(element[2])))

   print(d)
```

Comment: Or you can use `d.setdefault(word, []).append(...)` (with a regular `dict` rather than a `defaultdict`).

Comment: @Martijn that's nice, I didn't know about this one... But it seems a bit weird to me (especially /not this case/ if you had multiple branches in code that can fill the dictionary and you would have to copy default value to every place).

Comment: Thank you! this worked for me! The defaultdict is new for me so thank you for giving me an alternative way! @Vyktor

Answer (score 0):

Here's some simple code that does what you're looking for.

```
from collections import defaultdict
from pprint import pprint


class Counter(object):
    __slots__ = ('year', 'count')

    def __init__(self, year, count):
        self.year = year
        self.count = count

    def __str__(self):
        return "Counter(year=%d, count=%d)" % (self.year, self.count)

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.__str__()


def import_counts():
    counts = defaultdict(list)
    with file('data.csv') as f:
        for line in f:
            name, year, count = line.split(',')
            name, year, count = name.strip(), int(year.strip()), int(count.strip())
            counts[name].append(Counter(year, count))

    return counts

pprint(import_counts())
```

However, I changed the data format into a proper CSV as below.

```
song, 2000, 184950
boom, 2009, 83729
boom, 2010, 284500
boom, 2011, 203889
pow, 2000, 385920
pow, 2001, 248930
```

The output generated is as below:

```
{
    'boom': [
        Counter(year=2009, count=83729),
        Counter(year=2010, count=284500),
        Counter(year=2011, count=203889)
    ],
    'pow': [
        Counter(year=2000, count=385920), 
        Counter(year=2001, count=248930)
    ],
    'song': [
        Counter(year=2000, count=184950)
    ]
}
```

Do note that the above doesn't validate input and would error if given an invalid CSV.